# Set Xmx and Xms for java application running on k8s

Tags: java, kubernetes

I've an application running on k8s and would like to updated the java heapsize .
I've updated the JAVA_OPTS environnement variable and set it in the deployment file as below

```
- name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: "-Xmx768m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"
```

but when i run the below command it looks like my changes does not takes effect

```
 java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
     intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0                                   {pd product}
    uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0                                   {product}
    uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520                            {product}
    uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 33554432                            {product}
    uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728                           {product}
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 536870912                           {product}
     intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024                                {pd product}
     intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 1024                                {pd product}
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.12.0) (Alpine 8.212.04-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
```

I'm i wrong can someone help me and explain how to set hose values ?

Comment: If you upgrade to JDK11, or the latest Java8, you don't need these values as the full container space will be used

Comment: This is an open source application i not able to perform the upgrade i'm just trying to understand and tune what i have now .

Comment: JDK 9 supports a new environment variable `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` to prepend options to those specified on the command line

Comment: Your alpine container is not the application, it only packages it. You should be able to pick a newer JRE container and put your application inside it (building a new image rather than pulling from Docker Hub, if you have to). Other than that, it is unclear where you are running `java` from. Did you `kubectl exec` to the container? Note that any container can choose to ignore `JAVA_OPTS`

Comment: @OneCricketeer , yes i use kubectl exec to the container and run java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'

Comment: You might want to run `ps -aux | grep java` to look at the running process to see if the JVM options are set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you used OpenJDK Alpine to deploy a JAVA application, so you need to use this environment "**JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS**" instead of "**JAVA_OPTS**", something like:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: jvm_options
    image: xxx:xxx
    env:
    - name: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
      value: "-Xmx768m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"
```

Once your application is running, you can check the application log and you will find the log below:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx768m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
```

Comment: Thanks for your help i see this in my app log `08-Dec-2021 10:14:32.034 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024m
 2021-12-08T10:14:32.035330795Z 08-Dec-2021 10:14:32.035 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m`   . Does this mean that it takes effect ?

Comment: I think you should verify it like what you did in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command and args under the containers section for this. for example:

```
      containers:
      - name: test
        image: test:latest
        command: ["java"]
        args: ["-Xms256m","-Xmx768m","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: Depending on the container, `JAVA_OPTS` would do the same thing, though